# Kanji etymology of 毎?

Tags: kanji, etymology, chinese, radicals

what does 母 have to do with 毎? is there any link at all or did it come together randomly? does it have to do with the Chinese pronunciation?

Answer (score 6):

According to [the Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%AF%8F#Glyph_origin), the 母 portion is purely phonetic -- that is, it has to do with the [ancient] Chinese pronunciation.

Comment: Which has been reconstructed as /*mɯʔ/ or /*mˁəʔ/, fwiw. "Muh", in common with most baby words for "mother" across human languages. The word for 'each' had the same pronunciation and no obvious illustration, so they just went with that.

Answer (score 6):

「每{まい}」([Baxter-Sagart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)) [OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Chinese): **/*mˤəʔ/**; *Shinjitai*:「毎」) was originally a picture of a *woman*「女」wearing a *headdress*, indicating the meaning *married woman > adult woman, mother*.「女」was later *phoneticised* into「母{も}」(**/*məʔ/**). The meaning *married/adult woman* is no longer associated with the character「每」, and the modern meaning of「每」(*each, every*) is a phonetic loan.

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[粹](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)340
[合集27633](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=27633&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
尊
[集成6014](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=6014&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image]
[屮部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77389&page=30)
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd><kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han)
[隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
[image]
費鳳碑</kbd>
　<kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

> - *Phoneticisation* is the name of a change which transforms or replaces one component to another component which gives a sound indication to the character.
> - 「母」and「女」were very similar glyphs - the only difference between the two is that「母」draws out two dots, indicating *nipples* > *breasts*, emphasising the meaning *mother*.
>
>   <kbd>商
>   甲
>   [image]
>   [鐵](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)164.1
>   [合集3091](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=3091&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
>   金
>   [image]
>   農卣
>   [集成5424](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=5424&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)・[齊](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi_(state))
>   金
>   [image]
>   齊侯盤
>   [集成10159](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=10159&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
>   [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
>   [image]
>   [{{kr:包}}2](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)・83</kbd>
>   　<kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
>   簡
>   [image]
>   [睡・封](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)86</kbd>
>   　<kbd>今
>   楷
>   [image]</kbd>
> - In the earliest inscriptions,「每」was used as a variant of「母」due to the similar meanings and sounds, and you can view the headdress shape or the nipple dots as differentiating marks to distinguish「母」or「每」from「女」.

In the original sense of *woman*,「每」is a semantic component in e.g.「毓」, which is now replaced by「育」. See [Is 云 related to  in any way?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/64824/26510)

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [Multi-function Chinese Character Database](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/)
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究{{kr:所}}《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Answer (score 2):

每, the old form kanji of 毎, has 母 in it. My dictionary says that 每 is 
a pictogram representing a woman wearing a hair accessory (presumably, every day).

Comment: Hard to blame the dictionary when you don't cite it, but wherever you heard that it's completely wrong. It's phono-semantic, like Mr Utlendi said. Beyond which, the woman in the pictogram would presumably cover her nipples before bothering to set her hair in order...

Comment: @lly this answer is largely correct. The only thing that's wrong is that the character structure/origin of 每 has anything to do with "every (day)". It doesn't, and 每 is only a phonetic loan.

Comment: It's 新漢語林 2nd edition. It also mentions that Shuowen Jiezi explains 毎 is a phono-semantic compound but the dictionary editors are apparently against that theory. You can find a similar explanation in https://okjiten.jp/sp/kanji377.html

Answer (score 0):

It is because every person has a mother. The top part is 人. Every human has a mother.

Comment: This might be a useful mnemonic (to those who like mnemonics), but it doesn't seem to be the actual etymology of the character.